# How to completely hide API Url in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

This could be a familiar question but after googled I’m still confused on how to protect my API Url from someone who wants to view my API Url.

Does a native node module can do that?

Any advises would be great!

Comment: No, one could easily use wireshark without even looking at your apps code, also dont forget electron is not compiled when its built it just a package, like a zip/rar file, you should instead look into securing your API by using jwt and ssl

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will take a look into it.